# installing tensorflow with gpu in windows fails with exception

Tags: windows, tensorflow, gpu, anaconda

I have search all over and I now Im on the verge of just giving up. 
The cpu version of tensorflow installs just fine but I want to use the gpu. I have before used theano with gpu with CUDA8 and cuDNN 5.1 so they should be ok.
I have also tried to install the nightly build of tensorflow with the same result.

Any suggestions on what to check next. I'm this close to throw it all away, install virtualbox and ubuntu and run everything from there (don't want to though because of prestigious reasons :) ).

```
(C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Jens\Documents>pip install tensorflow-gpu  
Collecting tensorflow-gpu   
Using cached tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl  
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.1.0 in         c:\users\jens\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)  
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\jens\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)  
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\jens\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)  
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\jens\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
check_dist_requires_python(dist)  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
feed_parser.feed(metadata)  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 177, in feed
self._input.push(data)  
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 101, in push
parts = data.splitlines(True)  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'*
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in `pip`... haven't seen that before! Have you tried upgrading `pip` using the command `pip install -U pip`, then installing `tensorflow-gpu` again?

Comment: I already had `pip 9.0.1`. Tried to downgrade to 8.0.1 and then run the `pip install -U pip` command. Got 9.0.1 back.
`pip install tensorflow-gpu` gives the same error again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about pip.
I did have som issues with pip itself as well but solving that did help my tensorflow install unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem with Anaconda itself and not with TensorFlow, could you please try:

1. Uninstall TensorFlow
2. Install TensorFlow with `conda install`

Also see [this issue on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7556).
I'd suggest as well, but with a caveat because I didn't test this one, to download [a nightly build](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/99/) and install it instead of the PYPI package.

edit: now that I saw @mrry already had pointed you the direction to take so that might work.

Comment: I cannot uninstall tensorflow since it never installs, but I tried the conda install.
It works, which is good, but it gives me the same cpu version as `pip install tensorflow`. Which also works.

Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You where both on the right track. I did a clean install of Anaconda3 and created two new environments. One for theano and one for tensorflow.

With the clean install I could use
`pip install tensorflow-gpu`
Now both theano and tensorflow works with GPU.

Thanks